# User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

Tags: arduino-nano, adafruit

I am facing issues while uploading sketch to **Adafruit Feature 32u4 Bluefruit LE** devices. When i try to upload **Blink** demo it was working fine and my device also blinking, But bellow error i am getting every time when i upload sketch.

```
   System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
     User configuration file is "/Users/myMacmnin/.avrduderc"
     User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping
```

I am using **Adafruit Feature 32u4 Bluefruit Le device,Arduion 1.8.3 version, MacMini with macOs Sierra(10.12.3).**

Comment: That's not an error. That's just mentioning that you don't have a custom configuration file (which not many people do have) and it doesn't care.

Comment: Are you actually experiencing a problem, or are you just moaning that avrdude is printing messages?

Comment: Actually i am trying to uploading Neopixel sketch , I am getting this error, and nothing happen in device side. If you know anything about this please help me.

Comment: Select the right port? As I say, that's not an error. If you're not getting anything else out of it then you should maybe look at the debugging output and for the command being run and make sure that it's all correct.

Comment: Yes i selected correct Port,Board and programmer and i fallow Adafruit app for uploading sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found answer for my question, It happen because of uploading sketch in selected pin.

```
// Neopixel
//#define PIN            6   /* Pin used to drive the NeoPixels */
#define PIN            13   /* Pin used to drive the NeoPixels */
```

I Changed Pin 6 to 13 , it's worked for me.